# PHP: Can't get the selected value of a combobox

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the selected value of a combobox in php but the only result I get is "1" no matter what value is selected.

Here is my html code:

```
                                      <form name="form" method="POST" action="">
                                        <select class="dropdown-select"  name="dayscombo" id="dayscombo">
                                        <option value="1">7</option>
                                        <option value="2">30</option>
                                        <option value="3">90</option>
                                        <option value="4">365</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </form>
```

I'm trying to echo the selected value using:

```
$mydays=$_POST['dayscombo'];
echo "$mydays";
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is your submit ?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that.
Here it is: <button type="submit" name="Addcode">Add key</button>
And the php code:
if (isset($_POST['Addcode'])){

}

The sumbit works but the result is wrong.

Comment: add `var_dump($_POST);` and show us what you get

Comment: Check what is send by the browser using the network tab inside your browsers development console. It shows you exactly what request is done and what data is send. This sniffs a bit of the form getting sent by ajax, not by pure html means.

Comment: @Dagon I got array(3) {
  ["dayscombo"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["code"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Addcode"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: then 90 *must* of been selected

Comment: Yes, 7 was selected but how do I echo the result (like "7", "30" etc)?

Comment: if you want 7,30, etc make that the value. the *value* is returned

Comment: @user2921419 why don't you set your value equal to your text? like `<option value="7">7</option>`

Comment: @YerkoPalma you should post that as an answer

Comment: I changed the code to    <option value="7">7</option>
           <option value="30">30</option>
           <option value="90">90</option>
           <option value="365">365</option>

but I still get "1" as a result no matter what value is selected. Should I change "echo $_POST['dayscombo']  to something else?

Comment: your dump of $_POST above clearly shows you got **3** so im confused

Comment: Ok, I'm a noob so please explain it to me. I have this piece of code: $mydays=$_POST['dayscombo']; 
echo $mydays;
var_dump($_POST); 

When I click the submit button I get "1" which is the result of "echo $mydays" and then "array(3) { ["dayscombo"]=> string(2) "90" ["code"]=> string(0) "" ["Addcode"]=> string(0) "" }" which is the result of var_dump right?

Comment: remove everything else from the page, make sure its the right file, something odd is going on

Comment: I will. Anyways, thanks for helping me! I will mark the question as solved and I'll try to remove everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your value equal to your text like `<option value="7">7</option>`

Answer (score -2):

Are you using jQuery? Where is the send button? Try it:

```
//send.php
<form name="form" method="POST" action="posted.php">
<p>
<select class="dropdown-select"  name="dayscombo" id="dayscombo">
<option value="1">7</option>
<option value="2">30</option>
<option value="3">90</option>
<option value="4">365</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<button type="submit">POST</button>
</p>
</form>

//posted.php
<?php
$mydays = $_POST['dayscombo'];
echo "$mydays";
?>
```

Running link: http://missoesrestauradoras.com.br/send.php

Best Regards!